# Is there any way to implement only owner access control in solana anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I want the wallet that deployed the smart contract to be the owner of that smart contract and I need to set up access control such that only the owner of that program will be able to call any function. Need help as to how do I implement this. Need to implement this in anchor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All executable programs (smart contracts) are owned by the [BPF loader](https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/programs#bpf-loader).

What you refer to as the "owner" in this case, will be the upgrade authority.

You can implement access control checks by passing in an account as a signer and checking that account against public key(s) that should have access to call the function.

e.g.

- Public key `mYCustomPublickey12345` should be able to call any function
- From the client: public key `mYCustomPublickey12345` has to sign the transaction
- Program: validates that `mYCustomPublickey12345` signed the transaction

If `mYCustomPublickey12345` hasn't signed the transaction, return an error.

---

edit:

This seems to be exactly what you're looking for:
https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/accounts/program/struct.Program.html

Comment: do I type out the public key in the access control function? is there no variable in anchor that can store the upgrade authority?

Comment: This seems to be what you're looking for: https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/accounts/program/struct.Program.html

Comment: thanks this has been really helpful. Any Idea how I would be able to do this if the Smart Contract was not upgrade able and did not have an upgrading authority?

Answer (score 1):

**anchor example**

This `Initialize` instruction can be called only by `Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS`

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(random: String)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {

    #[account(mut,address=pubkey!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS"))]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    ...

}
```

This will make sure that only the `Signer` with `address` `Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS` can call this instruction.